# Modify Last item in list

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string, int>` and I want to modify the int of the last Item.

How do I do this?

I've found the method `.Last<T>` But I cant see how to use it.

Comment: There is no such thing as `List<T, V>`

Comment: what is `List<string, int>`, that's not a valid DS, are you using `SortedList<string,int>`

Comment: `Dictionary`, perhaps?

Comment: I assume you mean a `List<(string, int)>`?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yes sorry, I am getting confused between languages!

Comment: It might be best to delete this and post a new question with a clear example of what you want and where you are stuck. Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @Chud37 - Please edit your question so it is clear what exactly is the type you are working with and what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you are using a `SortedList<string, int>`, in which case you have to do this indirectly by using the last key in the `.Keys[]` array to access the last element of the `SortedList`, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var test = new SortedList<string, int>();

            test.Add("one", 1);
            test.Add("two", 2);

            test[test.Keys[test.Count - 1]] = 3;

            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"test[{item.Key}] == {item.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
test[one] == 1
test[two] == 3
```